# setup an environment so that users can collaborate on code editing

Tags: environment, sharing

In our Department we have researchers working on different projects and would like to share codes  (Python, Perl, R, batch scritp etc..) with other researchers on the same Ubuntu 18.04 server. All researchers have an account on the server.

What environment, solution or software would you propose to do that?

I have googled for such solution but came up with too many options which i honestly am not familiar with.
I am looking for something simple to implement and easy to use.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: can you please be more specific, what kind of sharing, just copying flies from one another, like shared folder? managing projects and collaborating like GIT? or live coding together on the same file like google docs

Comment: They want to be able to share and collaborate codes like GIT but locally on the server - not with the outside world, if that makes sense.

Comment: then I would suggest local gitlab setup https://about.gitlab.com/install/, even easier in container https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share your code with other researchers of the same department, you should use `vsftpd` for file transferring (note that IP addresses of each device should be in range of your department network) with a specified shared folder.

It's even better to use GitHub (with private repository, add other collaborators) for project management, you can add issues, to-do, view edits, etc. and they'll get notified.

Alternatively, you can use AnyDesk or TeamViewer, etc. famous software programs to make teamwork a success quickly. You can transfer files from it too.

Comment: Thank you @Linux Man I will look into vsftpd